# Real time web crawler detection

Tags: apache, web-services, webserver, web-crawler, real-time

I've seen so many people have detected web crawlers by using web logs. But i wonder why we can't use real time traffic to detect web crawlers ? I would like to know if there is a way to detect web crawlers from the traffic which are coming in real-time.